# How to properly manipulate a list?

Tags: c#

Good afternoon folks,

Logic noob here again with another question. I am using my logic incorrectly to handle the data from the following list.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public static List<string> itemDescription = new List<string>();
    public static List<double> itemPrice = new List<double>();
    public static List<int> itemQoh = new List<int>();

    public static List<string> salesCustomerName = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> salesItemDescription = new List<string>();
    public static List<double> salesItemPrice = new List<double>();
    public static List<int> salesQuantity = new List<int>();
```

I am using these two methods with this logic in mind:

GetPrice()

- Prompt user to enter a price
- Validate the value is a double and greater than 0
- Return the price entered 
  My issue is understanding the tryparse method

```
public static double GetPrice() {
      // prompt the user to enter a price
      Console.WriteLine("\nEnter a new price: ");
      // validate value is double and greater than 0
      double price;
      string newPrice = Console.ReadLine();
      bool isDouble = Double.TryParse(newPrice, out price);
      if(isDouble | price > 0) {
        Console.WriteLine("Double data type has been detected.");
      }
      // return the price entered
      itemPrice.Add(price);
      return price;
    }
```

GetQuantity
 - Prompt user to enter a price
 - Validate the value is a int and greater than 0
 - Return the price entered

```
public static int GetQuantity() {
      // prompt the user to enter a quantity
       Console.WriteLine("\nEnter a quantity: ");
      // validate value is integer and greater than or equal to 0
      int quantity;
      string newQuantity = Console.ReadLine();
      bool isInt = Int32.TryParse(newQuantity, out quantity);
      if(isInt | quantity > 0) {
        Console.WriteLine("Int data type has been detected.");
      }
      // return the quantity entered
      itemQoh.Add(quantity);
      return quantity;
    }
```

Am I using this correctly? Anything helps! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly,

```
if(isInt | quantity > 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("Double data type has been detected.");
  }
```

and

```
if(isDouble | price > 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("Double data type has been detected.");
  }
```

should run only when *both* price/quantity is greater than 0 and the input value is a double/integer.

You are using a bitwise OR operator; for boolean conditionals, you double up the operator (so OR is || and AND is &&).

With that, since you seem to be interested in an AND, it should be (for the double case, leave int as an exercise for you):

```
  if(isDouble && price > 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("Double data type has been detected and value greater than zero.");
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I didn't notice I was asking for the double twice as well, sorry for the confusion. One is to verify it is an int and the other is the verify it is a double. Then my tryparse was done correctly? If I am understanding this correctly. I will use AND, that was my error.

Comment: Yes, the tryparse seems to be right--switching to AND should fix it for you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you meant to do a logical OR (||) instead of bitwise

```
  if(isDouble || price > 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("Double data type has been detected.");
  }
```

But you said *Validate the value is a double and greater than 0* and thus I would make it a `&&` AND condition rather

```
  if(isDouble && price > 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("Double data type has been detected.");
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I needed the AND condition! Ahh!